# Вычислите точные размеры панели (включая внутренние) для использования в Custom ScrollBar

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, **как узнать внутренние размеры панели**, которые скрыты от глаз пользователя, если элементов много, и свойство AutoScroll = false.

**На скрине указана цифра - она получена "случайно", в проекте все подписано.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**При получении координат последнего внутреннего элемента, полученное значение в разы меньше того значения, которое используется, чтобы добраться до этого элемента.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public Form_Main() {
        InitializeComponent();

        flp_Elements.MouseWheel += Flp_Els_MouseWheel;
    }

    // Scrolling the panel (Flp_Els) with the mouse wheel
    private void Flp_Els_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        int step = customScrollBar1.Value -= e.Delta > 0 ? customScrollBar1.SmallStep : -customScrollBar1.SmallStep;
        customScrollBar1.Value = Math.Max(customScrollBar1.Minimum, Math.Min(step, customScrollBar1.Maximum));

        ScrollValue = (int)customScrollBar1.Value;
    }

    // Scroll the panel (Flp_Els) with the slider on the ScrollBar
    private void customScrollBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ScrollValue = customScrollBar1.Value;
    }

    // Метод переопределения максимального значения, при добавлении элементов на панель
    private void flp_Elements_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
        // Получилось прокрутить дальше (3820) max - дальше не двигается,
        // но число максимума больше указанного выше

        // ! КАК ПОЛУЧИТЬ РАЗМЕРЫ ПАНЕЛИ, КОГДА ОНА НАПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ЭЛЕМЕНТАМИ И СКРЫВАЕТ ИХ

        customScrollBar1.Maximum = flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum + flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.LargeChange * 8;
        flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum = customScrollBar1.Maximum;
    }

    // БЕЗ ЭТОГО СОДЕРЖИМОЕ ПАНЕЛИ НЕ ДВИГАЛОСЬ
    // Установка пределов для панели
    public int scrollValue = 0;
    public int ScrollValue {
        get { return scrollValue; }
        set {
            scrollValue = value;

            // Minimum = 0 - все в пиклелях
            if (scrollValue < 0) scrollValue = 0;

            // Maximum - все в пиклелях
            if (scrollValue > flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
                scrollValue = flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Maximum;

            flp_Elements.VerticalScroll.Value = scrollValue;
        }
    }
}
```

На данный момент: панель прокручивается с помощью ScrollBar, но чтобы все работало правильно нужно это самое число.
Пробовал разные варианты, но они не работают, как нужно:

1. [Первый вариант](https://progi.pro/vichislenie-procenta-prokrutki-scrollbar-visota-scrollbar-bar-7799642)
2. [Второй вариант (описан в разделе "Calculations"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226381/Scrolling-Panel)

Comment: Код, относящийся к вопросу, нужно всьавить в сам вопрос. Вопрос из ссылок потеояет смысл сразу как только сломаются ссылки. StackOverflow - это база знаний, и ваш вопрос и ответ на него могут оказаться полезными для будущих посетителей. Оформите вопрос в соответствии с этим, пожалуйста.

Comment: Хорошо, сделаю это днём, за компьютером.

Comment: Для дочерних элементов найти максимальный Bottom и минимальный Top, а потом вычесть?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void flp_Container_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
    flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum = flp_Container.GetPreferredSize(flp_Container.Size).Height - flp_Container.Size.Height;
    VScrolBar1.Maximum = flp_Container.VerticalScroll.Maximum;           
}
```